# Cannot receive android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED when BroadcastReceiver is registered dynamically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to register a BroadcastReceiver programmatically to receive `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED`.  However, the `onReceive()` method never gets triggered.  The same BroadcastReceiver class I created works fine if I register is statically in the app's manifest file.

Why is this the case?  Is there a way to troubleshoot this?  I need to register dynamically because my BroadcastReceiver class contains members that I want a service to query later on.  If I catch this Intent statically then I have no easy way of querying these members because I believe the instance of BroadcastReceiver gets deleted as soon as `onReceive()` finishes.  Is this correct?  I am pretty sure this is the case considering the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) has the following to say about this:

> If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a  tag, then the object is no longer alive after returning from this function.

UPDATE 1:

Here is my dynamic registration code:

> ```
>   if (externalStorageListener == null)
>     {
>         Log.d(TAG, "creating externalStorageListener...");
> ```

```
        IntentFilter filterExternalStorage = new IntentFilter();
        filterExternalStorage.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        filterExternalStorage.addDataScheme("file");

        filterExternalStorage.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        externalStorageListener = new ExternalStorageBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver(externalStorageListener, filterExternalStorage);           
    }
```

Here is the intent filter in my manifest that actually works:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have similar problem and I figured out it's because of my activity called `finish()` and cause the broadcast unregistered.

Answer (score 3):

Occasionally, to receive android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED with dynamically created BroadcastReceiver one is to have android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS defined in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED action can be handled by privileged system application only. That action can not be received by 3rd party applications

Comment: Please add the Android version your answer is valid for. Are there work arounds for non privileged apps?

Answer (score -1):

May be when you create receiver dynamically your intent filter is different compared to when it is created through the `<receiver/>` tag?  Could you show us both your manifest part and the code part?

Also, instead of storing data in receiver's fields, you could consider other options:

- A content provider
- Shared preferences
- A singleton object

In that case there will be no difference between statically and dynamically created receivers.

EDIT: Based on the provided code, the problem is probably in [priority setting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29):

> Applications must use a value that is larger than SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY and smaller than SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY .

[SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY) = 1000

Comment: I have added a comment to my answer.  It is probably the priority settings that causes the problem. @gonzobrains

Comment: I was using Integer.MAX_VALUE for the priority, which is much higher than 1000.  Is that a problem?  I cannot imagine that being a problem if the intent can be received via the static manifest method.

Comment: I tried using SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY but it still doesn't work.  Could it be that my dynamically-registered receiver misses the intent at boot up?  That is when my sdcard is mounted.  Is there a way I can force an unmount and remount to see if it will get caught later?  I tried to adb shell and perform a umount but I get a permission denied.

Comment: Could you try without setting any priority value?